# How can i count the number of rows in a table based on one field while trying to use other fields as well in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 3 tables joined and I want to write a query which returns some fields from these joined tables.
There is a condition which I need to check against, and that is the number of rows specific to one user only.
To be more precise and clear, my tables look like this :

```
tblTest
------------------------------
TestID  | StudentID | TestType
------------------------------

tblTestType
---------------------------
TestType | TestName 
---------------------------

tblStudents
-------------------------------
StudentID | StudentName | Sex
-------------------------------
```

I am trying to get the list of students who have succeeded an exam in the first time (thus 'tblTest' resulting row count should be equal to 1 to indicate the fact that the user just took an exam and passed it, any number more than that means the student has taken that exam more than once),
and my query looks like this:

```
SELECT       tblStudents.StudentName, COUNT(tblTest.StudentID) AS [Number of Times Exame is Taken], tblTest.TestID
FROM            tblTest INNER JOIN
                         tblTestType ON tblTest.TestID = tblTestType.TestType INNER JOIN
                        tblStudents ON tblTest.StudentID =tblStudents.StudentID
GROUP BY tblTest.StudentID, tblTest.TestID
HAVING        (tblTest.TestID = 1)
```

Which fails. Can someone please show me the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I don't get what `TestID` and `TestType` are - why do you join on `tblTest.TestID = tblTestType.TestType` and not on `tblTest.TestType = tblTestType.TestType`? Is there a relation and if yes, what is `tblTest.TestType` good for?

Comment: I am using Visual Studios builtin query designer,I selected the columns and it created the join statements.TestType is the id representing the exam,for example we can have a list like:
TestType   TestName                                                   
1          Computer Algorithm                                       
2          Computer Programming                                     
i did this in case i decided to change the name to something else and save myself the trouble of changing the hardcoded names in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblStudents
  WHERE StudentID IN (
    SELECT StudentID
      FROM tblTest
      GROUP BY StudentID, TestID
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT       
tblStudents.StudentName, 
COUNT(tblTest.StudentID) AS [Number of Times Exame is Taken], 
MIN(tblTest.TestID) AS TestID
FROM            
tblTest 
INNER JOIN tblTestType ON tblTest.TestID = tblTestType.TestType 
INNER JOIN tblStudents ON tblTest.StudentID =tblStudents.StudentID
GROUP BY tblStudents.StudentName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * from tblTestType T
join
    (SELECT    tblStudents.StudentID, 
               COUNT(*) AS [Number of Times Exame is Taken], 
               tblTest.TestID
    FROM      tblTest
    GROUP BY  tblTest.StudentID, tblTest.TestID
    HAVING COUNT(*)=1 )a
ON a.TestID = T.TestType
INNER JOIN tblStudents
ON a.StudentID =T.StudentID
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're after?

```
WITH cteTest AS (
  SELECT COUNT(TestID) TakenCount, StudentID, TestType
  FROM tblTest
  GROUP BY StudentID, TestType
)
SELECT
    s.StudentName,
    tt.TestName
  FROM cteTest t
  INNER JOIN tblTestType tt ON t.TestType = tt.TestType
  INNER JOIN tblStudents s ON t.StudentID = s.StudentID
  WHERE t.TakenCount = 1;
```